# Debian not starting GUI

Tags: debian, x11, gnome

When I start Debian, the GUI is not starting. It goes to command line asking for login.

```
andre@move-01:~$ systemctl status gdm3 service
* gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-01-09 13:32:21 BRST; 12min ago
  Process: 952 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 952 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/gdm3" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 958 (gdm3)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.serivce
              958 /usr/sbin/gdm3
             1609 /usr/bin/Xorg :1 -novtswitch -background none -noreset -verbose 3 -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-Debian-gdm-0Mifhr/database -seat seat0 -nolisten tcp vt7

* service.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When I try to `sudo startx`, I get this:

```
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Can't read lock file /tmp/.X0-lock
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Other commands I've tried:

```
update-rc.d -f gdm defaults
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop && startx
```

What's going on?

*(There are similar questions, but neither of them worked for me.)*

---

#### EDIT

Output for `sudo journalctl -u gdm3`:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2017-01-09 13:55:54 BRST, end at Mon 2017-01-09 14:25:33 BRST. --
```

---

#### EDIT 2

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.  [AMD/ATI] Tahi
 PRO  [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
```

Comment: [Moved existing comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51504/discussion-on-question-by-mr-felix-debian-not-starting-gui) as discussed.

Answer (score 1):

For Nvidia-card try  Bootoption `nouveau.modeset=0`

For Intel `i915.modeset=0`

This disable the [KMS](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting)

Comment: +1, but my computer is AMD and no nvidia card.

Comment: Then  `radeon.modeset=0` But I am not familiar with amd/radeon cards.

Comment: Nice, I'll try!

Comment: Are you using the opensource driver or the fglrx (closed source) one?

Comment: @Bahamut Tried `radeon.modeset=0`, but nothing changed, only resolution changed, It reduced, I got big letters. @Bigon man, I don't know which one I'm using... :(

Comment: Also tried `startx` after `radeon.modeset=0`. Got same error...

Comment: Did you explicitly installed the closed source driver (it's a manual action, not coming with the default install)? What is the model of the card (`lscpi |grep VGA`)

Comment: I'll post the output in a question edit.

Comment: Done. You can check it there in the question.

Comment: Maybe stupid question. xorg is on your system? `dpkg -l | grep -i xorg`

Comment: Yes. Tested here and It's on.